# Prerender.io with Angular Universal - doesn't render HTML within component tags

Tags: html, angular, server-side-rendering, prerender

I have created an Angular Universal app that consists of nested components.
I need Prerender.io to return the Server-Side-Rendered HTML from my app but Prerender.io only returns the top level component tags and not the HTML within.

It seems that this happens to every Angular app (SRR or not). I would expect it to happen on a none-SSR page but not on SSR.

I followed the guidelines from [prerender.io](https://prerender.io):

```
git clone https://github.com/prerender/prerender.git
cd prerender
npm install
node server.js
```

And then tried to go to:

```
http://localhost:3000/http://localhost:4000/test
```

The returned html I get is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Documents SSR</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css">
    <style></style>
</head>

<body>
    <app-root _nghost-sc0="" ng-version="8.2.3" _nghost-serverapp-c0="">
        <router-outlet _ngcontent-serverapp-c0=""></router-outlet>
        <component1>
            <!---->
            <component2></component2>
        </component1>
    </app-root>

</body>

</html>
```

I would expect Prerender.io to render everything within `component2` but as you see, I get nothing.

**Am I missing a configuration somewhere or doesn't Prerender.io support Angular?**

If I go directly to `http://localhost:4000/test` I get the full rendered HTML.

**EDIT**

It could look like Prerender.io doesn't wait for my last ajax call to be done before rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue - don't use ShadowDom.
My `component2` was using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom`.
Removing that let Prerender give me the entire HTML.